# No known class method (facebook sdk integration)

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to add the `react-native-fbsdk-next` into my react-native app. The documentation says to add the following lines to the `AppDelegate.m` file to enable AEM (Aggregated Event Measurement)

```
#import <FBAEMKit/FBAEMKit.h>

[FBAEMReporter configureWithNetworker:nil appID:{app-id}];
[FBAEMReporter enable];
[FBAEMReporter handleURL:url]
```

After I added these lines of code like this:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
[FBAEMReporter configureWithNetworker:nil appID:123456789]; // in the code I use the real app Id
[FBAEMReporter enable];
[FBAEMReporter handleURL:url];
  #if defined(EX_DEV_LAUNCHER_ENABLED)
  if ([EXDevLauncherController.sharedInstance onDeepLink:url options:options]) {
    return true;
  }
  #endif
  return [super application:application openURL:url options:options] || [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

the build fails with the following error  `no known class method for selector 'configureWithNetworker:appID:'`. I can't find or understand how to fix this issue, the documentation doesn't provide any additional information/steps to follow. Any advise or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you're missing another parameter in this. [FBAEMReporter configureWithNetworker:nil appID:{app-id} {another Param}]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a mistake in the react-native-fbsdk-next README

the underlying method signature in the native Facebook iOS SDK is:

```
+ (void)configureWithNetworker:(nullable id<FBAEMNetworking>)networker
                     appID:(nullable NSString *)appID
                  reporter:(nullable id<FBSKAdNetworkReporting>)reporter;
```

So the call should be:

```
  [FBAEMReporter configureWithNetworker:nil appID:@"1234556" reporter:nil];
  [FBAEMReporter enable];
  [FBAEMReporter handleURL:url];
```

(note that appID is a string, also I am unfamiliar with the SKAdNetworkReporter but it is nullable so it builds passing in **nil**).